# Exporting Polylines from Outline Basemap

Tags: raster, shapefile, line, basemap

I'm trying to export the feature outlines from ESRI's "Outlines" basemap into a new polyline shapefile. Is there a way to accomplish this without the lines becoming a pixelated mess? My attempt at extracting these lines was to export a tiff image from the basemap, then run the Reclassify and Raster to Polyline tools to obtain my shapefile. The first image shows the initial basemap imagery, and the second image shows a closeup of the end result after running Raster to Polyline.

[image: Outline Map]

[image: Shapefile after Running Reclassify and Raster to Polyline]

Comment: Why not use the vector tile version of this map? https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=291da5eab3a0412593b66d384379f89f

Comment: Is there a way to extract the vector tiles to shapefile? Ultimately my end result is I want the features extracted to a polyline shapefile for use within another program.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: We primarily use ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1, however we also have (although seldom use) ArcGIS Pro. I'm using Pro to view the Outlines basemap and similarly the vector tile map you linked since Desktop can't view vector tile layers.

Comment: the vector tile should be in .pbf format you can use this https://github.com/rowanwins/arcgis-pbf-parser to geojson>gdb/shapefule

Comment: How do I export the vector tile layer to pbf? Also, I'm a bit lost with what to do with the provided github pbf parser. Is the "Basic Usage" code supposed to be copied into the Python environment in ArcGIS Pro? I appreciate the help, but I'm pretty novice at GIS Pro and github as well, so some of this is a bit over my head.